# How to Update one object in an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm making a simple Address Book Application using react-bootstrap. I've successfully implemented methods to Add a new contact or Delete an existing contact but I'm having trouble updating existing contacts. As of right now, when I press the 'edit' button to update a contact, a new contact is added with the 'updated' information, instead of replacing the selected contact. My Contacts are stored in an array of objects called 'people'

Here is my full source code: 
https://github.com/DeonChoi/address-book

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
            people: [],
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            address: '',
            city: '',
            country: '',
            postalCode: null,
            phone: null,
            email: '',
            age: null
        };
        this.editPerson = this.editPerson.bind(this);
    }

editPerson = (index) => {
   this.setState(state => {
            const people = state.people.map((person, personIndex) => {
                if (personIndex === index) {
                    person.newFirstName = this.state.firstName;
                    person.newLastName = this.state.lastName;
                    person.newAddress = this.state.address;
                    person.newCity = this.state.city;
                    person.newCountry = this.state.country;
                    person.newPostalCode = this.state.postalCode;
                    person.newPhone = this.state.phone;
                    person.newEmail = this.state.email;
                    person.newAge = this.state.age;
                    return person;
                } else {
                    return person;
                }
            });
            return {
                people,
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with current implementation?

Comment: The issue is that it adds this 'updated' contact as a new object in the array, instead of replacing the original object in the array

Comment: No it is not  adding a new object, a new copy of the array is created and the updated person object is still the same, only information is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editPerson = index => {
    let {people} = this.state;

    let peopleArr = people.slice();

    let user = peopleArr[index];
    user.newFirstName = this.state.firstName;
    user.newLastName = this.state.lastName;
    user.newAddress = this.state.address;
    user.newCity = this.state.city;
    user.newCountry = this.state.country;
    user.newPostalCode = this.state.postalCode;
    user.newPhone = this.state.phone;
    user.newEmail = this.state.email;
    user.newAge = this.state.age;

    peopleArr[index] = user;

    this.setState({
        people: peopleArr
    });
}
```

Comment: @ggovan Thank you for your feedback on the answers. Do you happen to have a solution? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!